# Multiple APN Support on Android Devices

Tags: java, android, multithreading, connectivity, apn

I am trying to use two threads each to open a webpage with different network type.
Thread 1 using `TYPE_MOBILE_HIPRI` and Thread 2 using `TYPE_MOBILE` using `requestRouteToHost()` method. But, in any case both the threads do not become true.
My,only concern is to check is there any way to get different IPs for diffrent APN used.

```
 class Thread1 extends Thread
    {   @Override
        public void run()
        {   URL url=null;
            try {
                url = new URL("http://216.58.196.110");
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            InetAddress iAddress = null;
            try {
                iAddress = InetAddress.getByName(url.getHost());
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Log.d("IP********","IP Address"+getIPasInt(iAddress));
            boolean b=connect1.requestRouteToHost(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE_HIPRI,getIPasInt(iAddress));
            Log.d("Request Route To Host1","Value"+b);
```

Answer (score 0):

My device has only 1 ip address but the same ip interacts with multiple ips as per request. I donot see any point in having multiple ips on the device